# How to trigger notification on certain condition?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using below cloud function in firebase-messaging for the notification purpose for notification to the user on change in firestore document, which is working working fine, but i want the notification to be trigerred only on if certain condition is achieved

```
exports.sendNotification2 = functions.firestore.document("users/{to_user_id}/notifications_received/{notification_id}").onWrite((change, context)=>{

      const to_user_id = context.params.to_user_id;
      const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
      const to_token_id = context.params.to_token_id;



      return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(to_user_id).collection('notifications_received').doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult=>{

          const from_user_id = queryResult.data().from_user_id;
          const to_token_id = queryResult.data().to_token_id;
          const to_user_id = queryResult.data().to_user_id;
          const notificaionmessage = queryResult.data().notification_message;
         
          const notification_id = queryResult.data().notification_id;
          const value = queryResult.data().value;

          const payload = {

              notification : {
                  title: notificaionmessage,
                  body: notificaionmessage,
                  icon:"default"
                              },

                              data: {

                                       click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK2',
                                       notification_id: notification_id,

                                       category: 'default'
                                     }
          };



         return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(to_token_id,payload).then(result=>{

              console.log("Notification Sent Successfulllllllllllll");
              return null;
          });

      }


      );

  });
```

I want when the `value` variable which is an number, is a multiple of hundered , only then the notification should be triggered.
I know the logic of `value%100 == 0` to check whether the number is multiple of hundered or not, but I am not able to get how to implement this logic?
Please guide me further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help! Just put the send notification code in `if` block and in `else` return `null` or something else.

```
if (value%100 === 0){
const payload = {

              notification : {
                  title: notificaionmessage,
                  body: notificaionmessage,
                  icon:"default"
                              },

                              data: {

                                       click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK2',
                                       notification_id: notification_id,

                                       category: 'default'
                                     }
          };



         return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(to_token_id,payload).then(result=>{

              console.log("Notification Sent Successfulllllllllllll");
              return null;
          });
}//end if block
else return null;
```